# npm ERR! with insight package during ember-cli install on Windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7, npm, ember-cli

I have node (0.10.5) and npm (1.4.6) installed like suggested. Using a Windows 7 64bit system.

During installing [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli) with `npm install -g ember-cli` I got the error `npm ERR! git clone 'C:\User\...'  Cloning into bare repository  'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\'` for the [insight](https://github.com/joefiorini/insight.git) dependency.

I could solve this by replacing the original **insight** dependency declaration

```
"insight": "git+https://github.com/joefiorini/insight.git#mobile-app",
```

in the **package.json** with

```
"insight": "git://github.com/joefiorini/insight.git#mobile-app",
```

I then ran into the problem that, while creating a new ember-cli project with `ember new my-app` ember-cli again tried to depend on the **insight** git repo via https, causing the same npm Error as mentioned before.

I then removed all the **insight** calls from the ember-cli source code, because the **insight** lib just provides statistical data about the ember-cli tool. I then was able to create a new ember-cli app and could also start the `ember server`.

Questions:

- I know that this can't be the right way to solve this issue!?
- So does anyone has a suggestion on how to get this thing right?
- Is it an ember-cli or a npm issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for adding the related links like that. I have a fresh SO account and I am not able to add more than two links in a post:

[My ember-cli fork](https://github.com/DarioSoller/ember-cli) with out the insight dependency. Further a few somehow related Github issues: [#228](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/228), [#240](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/240), [#160](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/160), [#214](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/214)

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I also tried cleaning the npm-cache, without any results. Could further maybe the branch selector `#mobile-app` at the end of the git URL cause a problem!?

Comment: I now guess that this issue is a git problem, caused by a wrong/damaged `libcurl-4.dll` reference of the msysgit, which could have happened because of using SourceTree and TortoiseGit at the same time. Will have to further investigate what really goes wrong!?

Answer (score 1):

I was bumping my head against the same wall, for me the solution was as simple as changing my path variable to point to git like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

my original path entry for git was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

I found the solution in the npm issue tracker here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2333

I just did this, so I'm not sure if this has any other unwanted side effects.

Comment: On a quick try, this couldn't solve the issue for me. I will keep this updated, if I am able to solve it in my next spare time tries. Anyway, thanks for sharing your solution and the link, was definitely worth trying!

Comment: Sorry to hear it wasn't this easy for you as well, my ember-cli install seems to work as it should for me after this fix, and I haven't noticed any negative side effects either. Could it be a case of trying so many things to fix the issue that new issues are introduced? I know I have walked down that dark path more then once..